# Force Solr not to use _version_ field during search

Tags: java, solr, lucene, full-text-search

I have a default  declaration for `_version_` field in my *schema.xml*:

```
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"
   multiValued="false"/>
```

I've read that this field is only internally managed by Solr for concurrency management, however when I search for "002219" in return I get:

```
"docs": [  
  {  
        "person_street_t": [  
          "<streetName>",  
        ],  
        "id": "123",  
        "person_abbr_t": [  
          "<sb>"  
        ],  
        "person_name_t": [  
          "<sb>"  
        ],  
        "person_city_t": [  
          "<city>"  
        ],  
        "person_zipcode_s": "<zipcode>",  
        "type_s": "PERSON",  
        "person_house_number_s": "<hn>",  
        "_version_": 1494523490022195200  
                            //****** <- matched by Solr
   }  
 ]
```

but I don't want Solr to search through that field.
Is it a normal behaviour? Am I doing something wrong? Or is there any other way to disable searching in `_version_` field?

UPDATE:

Okay, I've read a bit and found out that this field (_text) is defaultSearchField. So what I did for now is changing the default:

```
<copyField source="*" dest="_text"/>
```

to:

```
  <copyField source="*_t" dest="_text"/>
  <copyField source="*_s" dest="_text"/>
  <copyField source="*_ts" dest="_text"/>
  <copyField source="*_ss" dest="_text"/>
```

These are the only field types I'm indexing (*_ts was added by me). Will it be sufficient?

Comment: What's the default search field, its type and type defintion? What is your exact query URL?

Comment: I haven't set any default search field, so it must be set to Solr default. I'm doing this at work, so I'll be able to provide more details tomorrow.
P.S. Thanks for attention :)

Comment: How is your search handler configured? You do have one in your solrconfig.xml.

Comment: How do you index? Probably you have a catchall field in your import routine.

Comment: How is the rest of the schema? Should be the last question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used example schema, you most probably have **copyField** defined that copies everything to a single **text** field (defined in schema.xml) and searches that (defined in solrconfig.xml).

That's good for development, but everything is just searched as text, probably not something you want to do.

You can investigate switching to something like eDisMax. Or, if you are not quite ready, you can just define tighter *copyField* rules to only aggregate the fields you want.

Comment: You're right, I have: <copyField source="*" dest="_text"/>. But is it needed at all? What is this aggregate field used for? Will it be okay if I just remove it? All fields are already indexed 'on their own', aren't they?

Comment: It is needed with your current configuration, look for **df** field definition in your solrconfig.xml. Solr gives you a lot of flexibility in how you search, currently you are using the simplest option of everything meshed together into one field for search. Eventually, you will want to migrate from that to something like eDismax. Read the tutorials/Reference Guide for more information on that.

Comment: Thanks, just one more thing: can the copyField definitions I posted in updated question be used as a temporary solution?

Comment: I think they should be fine, yes.